# Random echo's on one button?

Tags: php, button, random, echo

I present my simple working button and echo.

```
   <p>
  <span style="text-align: center">
  <?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
echo "You pressed the button!";
}
?>
  </span>
<form method="post">
    <span style="text-align: center">
  <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Press me">
  </p>
    </span>
</form>
```

My question is two parts. Can I make one button randomize echo's in random order?
Second part, is yes. How do I do that?

Comment: Sorry but this question makes no sense at all.

Comment: So you can't have a list of echo's and each time the button is pressed, it gives you a new echo?

Comment: Yes you can echo a random item from an array

Comment: Give an example of what you actually mean. Add it to your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible, by using [`array_rand()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-rand.php).
Simply do something like this.

```
<?php 

$randomStrings = array(
    'some silly string',
    'another silly string',
    'i like pizza and stuff',
);

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $keys = array_rand($randomStrings);
    echo $randomStrings[$keys[0]];
}
?>
```

<sup>*Pseudo code*</sup>

---

you could even do something like this, but you should rather use in-built php functions.

```
<?php 

$randomStrings = array(
    'some silly string',
    'another silly string',
    'i like pizza and stuff',
);

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $count = count($randomStrings);
    echo $randomStrings[rand(0, $count)];
}
?>
```

<sup>*You don't need to use the above `count()` as `array_rand()` will shuffle the actual array around allowing you to harness the random strings being chosen.*</sup>

Comment: @ElizabetheDeSalisbiry Perfectly alright, glad it helped :)

Comment: This silly guy likes pizza too. +1 if you make it double olive. Kidding +1 ;)

Comment: @Fred-ii- I'm all about the meat-lovers with pineapple. hnggggg ;-)

Answer (score 0):

```
$replies = array('hey' , 'how are you' , 'good day to you');
echo $replies[rand(0, count($replies))];
```